# Android Add Link to a preference activity - how?

Tags: android, android-preferences

What is the way to add a clickable link to my preference activity?

Comment: plese see this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839679/button-in-preference-file

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following for three ways of doing it - [Android Patterns - Navigation](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_category/navigation). Look under "provide access to general operations for the current screen?"