# Button in preference file

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have set the two buttons in preference.xml file. I want to go to main activity when I click the "ok" button. So for that code is where to write?

Comment: Please provide some code that you already wrote and the preference.xml file.

Comment: "I have set the two buttons in preference.xml file" -- there are no buttons in preference XML resources. Buttons are widgets and go in layout XML resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an onPreferenceClickListener in your PreferenceActivity.

in preference xml :

```
<Preference android:title="Preference Button" android:summary="This works almost like a button" android:key="mypref" />
```

in preferences activity :

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            // Get the custom preference
            Preference mypref = (Preference) findPreference("mypref");
            mypref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() { });
}
}
```