# Add link to Preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have preferences in an Android Live wallpaper app as below. (These are checkboxes). I want to add a link to a Facebook page to this list. Looking at Android PreferenceCategory on the net, I don't see anything like "LinkPreference" or "ButtonPreference", but then again, a link or button isn't really a preference, so maybe I'm trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. Is this possible and if so, how?

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="showred"
            android:summary="Display red."
            android:title="Display red" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="showgreen"
            android:summary="Display green."
            android:title="Display green" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This question has been asked before:
[Android Add Link to a preference activity - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753747/android-add-link-to-a-preference-activity-how)
but not answered.

[Edit]
So now have the code below. It does go to Facebook, but only after first clicking on one of the checkbox preferences.

In livewallpaper_settings.xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings" >  
<Preference  
    android:key="facebook"  
    android:summary="@string/facebook"  
    android:title="@string/facebook" />  
</PreferenceCategory>
```

LiveWallpaperSettings.java:
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {
        Log.d("LiveWallpaperSettings.onSharedPreferenceChanged()", "key: " + key);
        final Preference mypref = (Preference) findPreference("facebook");
        mypref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
    Log.d("LiveWallpaperSettings", "mypref: " + mypref.getKey());
    if (mypref.getKey().equals("facebook")) {
    Log.d("LiveWallpaperSettings", "LINK TO FACEBOOK");
    openWebURL("http://www.facebook.com");
    return false;
    }
    return false;
} });
return;
}

public void openWebURL( String inURL ) {
    Log.d("openWebURL", inURL);
    Intent browse = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse( inURL ) );

    startActivity( browse );
}
```

Comment: But it has been answered, you just didn't click the link in the comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked that link. I will look at this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an [EditTextPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html)? You can use the same attributes as an `EditText` in your `EditTextPreference` so you can restrict the input to a single line and display the correct IME for email input etc.